# Measure angle between multiple vectors - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df containing various sets of xy points at successive time intervals. Using below, xy points of multiple subjects are referenced in `ID`, a single unique point is displayed in `moving_X` and `moving_Y` and a fixed xy point (`fixed_X`,`fixed_X`).

For each unique point in `ID` and `Time`, I'm trying to calculate the angle between the moving points and fixed points and moving points and ID points using their vectors.

Specifically, each `ID` point should return an angle ranging from 0 to π. To achieve this I want to use the algorithm below, where `V0` is each individual ID point, `V1` is the moving point, and `V2` is the fixed point. All points are expressed as vectors.

```
np.arctan2(abs(np.linalg.det([[V2 - V0],[V1 - V0]])), np.sum(V2 - V0,V1 - V0))
```

The attempt is returning `LinAlgError`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({              
    'Time' : [1,1,1,2,2,2],             
    'ID' : ['A','B','C','A','B','C'],      
    'X' : [2.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,2.0,1.0],
    'Y' : [3.0,1.0,-2.0,0.0,2.0,1.0],   
    'moving_X' : [3.0,3.0,3.0,3.5,3.5,3.5],
    'moving_Y' : [2.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],    
    'fixed_X' : [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],
    'fixed_Y' : [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0],        
    })

V0 = np.array(df['moving_X'], df['moving_Y'])
V1 = np.array(df['fixed_X'], df['fixed_Y'])
V2 = np.array(df['X'], df['Y'])

df['final_angle'] = np.arctan2(abs(np.linalg.det([[V2 - V0],[V1 - V0]])), np.sum(V2 - V0, V1 - V0))
```

Error:

```
raise LinAlgError('Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square')

LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

Intended Output:

```
   Time ID    X    Y  moving_X  moving_Y  fixed_X  fixed_Y  final_angle
0     1  A  2.0  3.0       3.0       2.0      0.0      0.0       1.3734
1     1  B  3.0  1.0       3.0       2.0      0.0      0.0       0.9828
2     1  C  4.0 -2.0       3.0       2.0      0.0      0.0       1.2278
3     2  A  2.0  0.0       3.5       1.0      0.0      0.0       0.3097
4     2  B  2.0  2.0       3.5       1.0      0.0      0.0       0.8663
5     2  C  1.0  1.0       3.5       1.0      0.0      0.0       0.2783
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to concatenate arrays Matlab-style, which doesn't quite work in Python. `np.array` takes one array as an argument, not multiple. `[[V2 - V0],[V1 - V0]]` will give you a 4-D array; I assume you want  `[V2 - V0 , V1 - V0]`.  If you want to do things Matlab style use `np.vstack` and `np.hstack`. Additionally, I'd recommend checking the array dimensions after each step to make sure they're what you expect, and confirming the axes along which the numpy `det` operation is operating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `[[V2 - V0],[V1 - V0]]` is not a square matrix, its shape is `(2, 1, 6)`.

I guess you are trying to copy the algorithm from

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/38725-find-angle-between-two-line

However in his example his matrix is of shape `(2,2)`

To vectorize the formula in the link, you need to convert it into `(6,2,2)`:

```
# note that they should be 2-D matrix
V0 = np.array([df['moving_X'], df['moving_Y']])
V1 = np.array([df['fixed_X'], df['fixed_Y']])
V2 = np.array([df['X'], df['Y']])

df['final_angle'] = np.arctan2(abs(np.linalg.det(np.dstack([(V2 - V0).T, (V1 - V0).T]))), np.sum((V2 - V0)*(V1 - V0), axis=0))
```

```
df['final_angle']

0    1.373401
1    0.982794
2    1.227772
3    0.309703
4    0.866302
5    0.278300
```

Comment: Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
V0 = df[['moving_X','moving_Y']].values
V1 = df[['fixed_X','fixed_Y']].values
V2 = df[['X','Y']].values

sines = np.abs(np.linalg.det(np.stack([V2-V0, V1-V0], axis=-1)))
```

Then you get:

```
array([ 5. ,  3. , 14. ,  2. ,  5. ,  2.5])
```

And similarly:

```
cosines = np.sum((V2-V0)*(V1-V0))
df['final_angle'] = np.arctan2(cosines, sines)
```

Output:

```
   Time ID    X    Y  moving_X  moving_Y  fixed_X  fixed_Y  final_angle
0     1  A  2.0  3.0       3.0       2.0      0.0      0.0     1.389329
1     1  B  3.0  1.0       3.0       2.0      0.0      0.0     1.461146
2     1  C  4.0 -2.0       3.0       2.0      0.0      0.0     1.096200
3     2  A  2.0  0.0       3.5       1.0      0.0      0.0     1.497533
4     2  B  2.0  2.0       3.5       1.0      0.0      0.0     1.389329
5     2  C  1.0  1.0       3.5       1.0      0.0      0.0     1.479309
```